# Getting (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed when trying to POST using FastAPI/ SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am getting the following error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: SignalJourneyAudienceConstraints.constraintId
[SQL: INSERT INTO "SignalJourneyAudienceConstraints" ("sourceId", "constraintTypeId", "constraintValue", targeting, frequency, period) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: (None, 10, 'STRING', 1, None, None)]
```

When trying to use the below endpoint. I have made all fields except:

- constraintTypeId: int
- constraintValue: str
- targeting: bool

As optional for the time being.

##### Endpoint

```py
# mail.py

...

@app.post("/add-new-audience-constraint", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
def add_new_audience_constraint(
    sjac: schema.SignalJourneyAudienceConstraints, db: Session = Depends(get_db)
):
    """Sets the main query data."""
    new_audience_constraint = models.SignalJourneyAudienceConstraints(
        constraintTypeId=sjac.constraintTypeId,
        constraintValue=sjac.constraintValue.upper(),
        targeting=True,
    )

    db.add(new_audience_constraint)
    db.commit()

    return {"message": "Data added successfully."}
```

##### Model

```py
# models.py 

class SignalJourneyAudienceConstraints(Base):
    """Signal Journey Audience Constraints"""

    __tablename__ = "SignalJourneyAudienceConstraints"
    constraintId = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    audienceId = Column(
        Integer,
        ForeignKey("SignalJourneyAudiences.audienceId"),
        primary_key=True,
    )
    sourceId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("SignalJourneySources.sourceId"))
    constraintTypeId = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey("SignalJourneyConstraintType.constraintTypeId")
    )
    constraintValue = Column(String)
    targeting = Column(Boolean)
    frequency = Column(Integer)
    period = Column(Integer)
```

##### Schema

```py
# schema.py
class SignalJourneyAudienceConstraints(BaseModel):
    """SignalJourneyAudienceConstraints BaseModel."""

    constraintId: Optional[int]  # PK
    audienceId: Optional[int]  # FK - SignalJourneyAudiences -> audienceId
    sourceId: Optional[int]  # FK - SignalJourneySources -> sourceId
    constraintTypeId: int  # FK - SignalJourneyConstraintType -> constraintTypeId
    constraintValue: str
    targeting: bool
    frequency: Optional[int]
    period: Optional[int]

    class Config:
        """config class"""

        orm_mode = True
```

I have looked into other SO questions, but none seem to fit what I am experiencing. Hopefully someone can explain what's going on and how to resolve it

#### ERD

[image]

Comment: You have two fields listed as `primary_key`; are they both primary keys? Since you have two fields, the primary key field will not automagically defined as an auto increment field; for that you want to only have one primary key, integer field. Since it's a ForeignKey field, it seems weird that it's also a primary key - are you sure about that being right?

Comment: This is how I read in the docs to create a composition key. I have I done this incorrectly?

Comment: No, if you need a composite key, this is the way. But then you have to include values for `constraintId` and `audienceId`, since they are supposed to uniquely identify a row in your table. If you want `constraintId` to autoincrement, there is no need for a composite key, since `constraintId` will always be a unique value.

Comment: Do you suggest removing the PK from `audienceId` ?  or would I need to give me `audienceId` a value in my end point? I just removed the pk from `audienceId` and still getting the error? I have confused myself now. 

I do need a comp key though?

Comment: I'm not sure. This depends on _what your goal is_ and what values/columns you expect to identify that row uniquely. Only you know how `audienceId` and `constraindId` are supposed to work - instead of doing random things; how do you want these two fields to work? Why are they a composite key? I'm not sure why you need a composite key - a composite primary key is a key that uses two columns to identify a row uniquely. Since you haven't included a value for either in your request, it seems you do not have two values that identify that row uniquely when you're inserting it.

Comment: I have added my ERD from `SignalJourneyAudienceConstraints` - `constraintId` and `audienceId` were meant to be a comp key. But looking at the diagram you're right the comp key isn't needed? There fore if I remove the PK from `audienceId` would my endpoint work ?

Comment: According to your ERD there is no composite key in `SignalJourneyAudienceConstraints`. You only need the single `constraintId` as `primary_key=True`

Comment: Thanks again. I think the comp key was a mis communication. Removed and all good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two fields listed as primary_key; are they both primary keys? Since you have two fields, the primary key field will not automagically defined as an auto increment field; for that you want to only have one primary key, integer field.

SQLAlchemy will only set the `auto_increment` property for SQLite automagically [when there is a single primary key column and it's defined as an integer](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#sqlite-auto-incrementing-behavior).

Since defining a composite key wasn't what you wanted, using `constraintId` as a single auto incrementing key (as shown in your ERD) is what you want - remove the `primary_key` entry for `audienceId` field.